# Creating QR code containing both text and photo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, qr-code

It is possible to create a QR code which contains both some text and photo (which is small logo) in python?

I mean text, which is not part of the photo. But I will have separately text (string variable) and photo (e.g. *.png).

So far I saw only the examples where it was possible to create a QR code from text or photo. I couldn't find example with both used at the same time.

Basically when I scan my QR code, I would like for it to show my photo (logo) and text information.

Comment: Even after an edit, the question title and body are both misleading.
I cite: « it was possible to create a QR code from text or photo ».
«QR code which contains both some text and photo».
Do you want to create a QR code that contains both text and photo, or from a picture containing also text in it ?
Image and photo(-graph) are synonyms, you made a mistake in your title.

Comment: I guess you could convert a VERY small image to base64 and store that in a qr code. If the text is also very small you could convert to base64 and store along-side of it with some sort of delimiter (perhaps a null byte) to distinguish the two parts. You would need to also code an app to read the qr code and interpret the returned base64 strings to turn them back into an image and text respectively. The better route is to store the image and text on a web page and store the URL in the qr code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment. QR Codes are used to encode text. So you have to read in your image, convert to base64, append your string with some delimiter and then write out your QR code.

Because we took special steps to encode the data (the image and the string) before storing in a QR code, we must also have a special application to read the QR code, split the base64 string by our delimiter, and then decode the base64 pieces into their appropriate media (writing the binary to a file for the image and printing out the decoded string).

All in all this will look something like the following:

```
import base64

#open image and convert to b64 string
with open("small.png", "rb") as img_file:
    my_string = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())

#append a message to b64 encoded image
my_string = my_string + b'\0' + base64.b64encode(b'some text')

#write out the qrcode
import qrcode
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=2,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
)
qr.add_data(my_string, optimize=0)
qr.make()
qr.make_image().save("qrcode.png")

#--------Now when reading the qr code:-------#
#open qr code and read in with cv2 (as an example), decode with pyzbar
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import cv2 #importing opencv
img = cv2.imread('qrcode.png', 0) 
barcodes = decode(img)

for barcode in barcodes:
    barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")

#split the b64 string by the null byte we wrote
data = barcodeData.split('\x00')

#save image to file after decoding b64
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(data[0]))

#print out message after decoding
print(base64.b64decode(data[1]))
```

Obviously this is only going to work for a VERY small image and just a little bit of text. You quickly blow out the max size of a QR code, and even before you hit the limits for the standard, you'll hit the limits for `qrcode` and `pyzbar` modules.

With this, you can start with a tiny image like:

[image]

And after encoding and appending text, have a qr code like:

[image]

And end up with the exact same picture and your appended text

Ultimately this really isn't terribly useful though since you have to have a special application to decode your QR code. The more traditional method of creating a web page with the content you want to share along with a qr code containing a link to the page, is a more user-friendly and approachable method to solving this.

Answer (score 0):

> when I scan my QR code, I would like for it to show my photo (logo) and text information

You can put the picture and the text on a public web page, and then encode the URL of the web page in the QR code.